# Does Data.Attoparsec.ByteString use "zero copy"ing?

Tags: haskell, bytestring, attoparsec

Take for example [takeWhile](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.11.2.1/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString.html#v%3atakeWhile). Internally it uses [span](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.0/docs/Data-ByteString.html#v%3aspan).

Does that mean it just references the input bytestring? Probably not, if so, is there a way to achieve this?

The motivating usecase is a large (>2gb) file that I want to map into memory and extract bytestrings pointing into the mapped memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, all substring-like operations on `ByteString`s are *O(1)*, as you can see in the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.0/docs/Data-ByteString.html#t%3aByteString), and make a shallow copy with a different offset/length.
If you don't need this, use `copy` to get a full copy of parsed results, so the original huge string could be garbage-collected.

Additionally, consider `Lazy` incarnations of `mmap` and `Attoparsec`, it may probably be more optimal in case of a consecutive parsing of the large chunk.